# Метки заставляют объекты создаваться и разрушаться?

Tags: c++, goto

Почему эта программа выводит `aAaA`, а не `aaAA` или `aA`?

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  A() { std::cout << "a"; }
  ~A() { std::cout << "A"; }
};

int i;

int main() {
a:A a;
  if (i-->=0) goto a;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну да, это то же самое, что написать:

```
do {
    A a;
} while (i-- >= 0);
```

объект локальный, и он каждый раз создается и  уничтожается

Comment: Это не совсем так.

Answer (score 4):

А что не так?

Зашли. Создался объект. Проверились - да, `i>=0`, пошли к метке `a`. Объект выходит из области видимости и уничтожается.

Создается новый. Проверка - `i<0` - все, идем дальше. Окончание программы, объект выходит из области видимости, уничтожается...

```
aAaA
```

Что не так? :)

Comment: Почему он выходит из области видимости не на строчке `}`, а на строчке `goto`? Получается, метки уничтожают объекты?

Comment: Он выходит из видимости на строчке `a:` :) Его между меткой `a:` и объявлением `A a;` не видно :)

Comment: @Harry, не на `a:`, а на `goto a`, иначе была бы попытка уничтожить объект до создания.

Comment: @Qwertiy Тогда уж "в момент перехода". В строке с `goto a` он вполне видим. Но откуда - попытка уничтожить до создания? При первом проходе там ничего не удаляется, потому что еще ничего не создано

Comment: Ну я в своём ответе написал сразу после, но по сути имею в виду "непосредственно перед jmp". Я имею в виду, что привязывать уничтожение чего-либо к меткам - так себе идея, потому что неизвестно, откуда делается переход и что конкретно надо уничтожать.

Comment: @Qwertiy Я написал, что в `a:` объект не виден, поэтому к этому моменту объект будет уничтожен. Я не скажу о букве стандарта, но привязывался бы к метке, потому что `goto` может быть куда угодно :)

Answer (score 2):

Добавим побольше точек вывода: https://ideone.com/C97AxT

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
  A() { cout << '+'; }
  ~A() { cout << '-'; }
};

int i;

int main()
{
  cout << '^';

a:
  cout << '0';
  A a;
  cout << '1';

  if (i-- >= 0) {
    cout << 'g';
    goto a;
  }

  cout << '$';
}
```

Получается:

```
^0+1g-0+1$-
```

Видим два создания объекта и 2 уничтожения. Уничтожения происходят в конце жизни объекта, который наступает сразу после `goto` и сразу после конца функции. Таким образом само по себе наличие `goto` не влияет на область жизни, влияет именно его исполнение.

Почему так делается, я точно не знаю, но у меня есть предположение. Компилятор обязан обеспечить корректность вызова конструкторов и деструкторов, а переход через goto в данном случае завершает блок - никакой другой возможности уничтожить переменную не будет. Теоретически, можно было бы пытаться уничтожить её после `g0`, но между `g` и `0` обратиться к ней затруднительно. Во-первых, очевидно, что в пару к goto поставить деструктор проще, во-вторых в принципе это выглядит логичнее - как конец блока по аналогии с break или continue, а не как неизвестное место перед вызовом конструктора (а если ещё один goto и он вообще не вызовется?). Два значения одна переменная хранить не может.

Почему я акцентировал влияние на данном случае? Потому что компилятор понимает, что переход делается выше переменной. Если мы немного переставим строки и поднимем объявление переменной выше метки (https://ideone.com/ZLK6xb), то она не будет уничтожена:

```
^+01g01$-
```

Comment: вопрос был почему *эта* программа выводит....?   И я не  понял что совсем не так в моем ответе и как  ваш ответ  это дополняет. Что в других случаях будет другой результат, это уже другая история и другой вопрос...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan 1. Не _"совсем не так",_ а _"не совсем так"._ 2. Не так то, что уничтожение происходит только в случае перехода по метке. Если переход по метке не происходит, то уничтожение в конце блока, а не там, где goto. А в случае с while уничтожение всегда при выходе из цикла, так что эти варианты не эквиваленты. 3. На вопрос _"почему"_ я тоже ответил. 4. Я ничей ответ не дополняю, он полностью мой. PS: И минус на твой ответ я НЕ ставил.

Comment: причем тут минус? Я хотел бы знать чем не эквивалентен вариант с циклом в данном конкретном случае(не вообще)?  Я  ведь не расстроен вашей критикой и не осуждаю, а просто обсуждаю.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, тут вопрос, что конкретно считать _"данным случаем"._ Для меня это только вот этот кусок: `a:A a; if (i-->=0) goto a;`, а в таком случае неэквивалентность в том, что если переход не выполнился, объект не уничтожен. Если ты для своего примера рассматриваешь кусок вместе со скобками `{ a:A a; if (i-->=0) goto a; }`, то да, он полностью эквивалентен твоему коду.

Comment: согласен, вот теперь понятно что вы имели ввиду